# Do a progress bar with timestamp

Tags: javascript, jenkins, progress-bar

I'm display some job with timestamp and I don't know how can I do a pregress bar with the timestamp.

I have 4 job:

- toto -> 1551164100895
- titi -> 1551164985234
- tata -> 1551165110259
- trtr -> 1551165270332

  ```
  function getDataAjax(param) {
  var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var oXhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = "../job/"+param+"/api/json?pretty=true";   
  var url2 = "../job/"+param+"/lastBuild/api/json?tree=result,timestamp,estimatedDuration";    

  oXhr.open('GET', url, true);
  oXhr2.open('GET', url2, true);
  oXhr.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var Data = data.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {       

      if (group.name) {
      getDataAjax(group.name);

      }
  })
  };

  oXhr2.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log("Timestamp "+ data.timestamp);   
  }
  oXhr.send(null);
  oXhr2.send(null);

  }
  // 1st appel
  getDataAjax("tpx-dev-stack-green-vm-reset");
  ```

How can I do a progress bar with timestamp ?

Thanks

Comment: What this progress bar should show?  Is there a deadline for each user?

Comment: This is unclear. It would be best for you to explain how your jobs work and how you expect to use the progress bar with timestamps. From what I understand, you need to have a `final` timestamp that you can compare your current timestamps to. This will allow you to get a percentage out of it (which will be used for your progress bar)

Comment: I'm using Jenkins api, so when a job finish is building, the progress bar grow up but the problem is that I have only timestamp like values... No deadline but estimated duration exist